# Where to download jsonserde jar file of amazon

Tags: json, hive, amazon-emr

enable to find `s3://elasticmapreduce/samples/hive-ads/libs/jsonserde.jar` on amazon server ?

could anyone please help me

Answer (score -1, accepted):

JsonSerde is class, included by hive-serde-1.0.jar. You can find it by this link [hive-serde-1.0.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/proofpoint/hive/hive-serde/1.0/hive-serde-1.0.jar)

Comment: There is org/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/DelimitedJSONSerDe.class in the apache-hive-1.2.1-bin/lib/hive-serde-1.2.1.jar. The limitation is that it can be used for serialization and not for deserialization. The OP was about the jar that Amazon provides.

Answer (score 2):

That is the correct location.  The following is the command I executed from an EC2 instance with S3 configured.

You can get aws command line tools and install them. 

`wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip
unzip awscli-bundle.zip
sudo ./awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws
aws configure`

After installing aws command line tool and listing the location s3://elasticmapreduce/samples/hive-ads/libs/ I see jsonserde.jar ..

`hadoop@ip-172-31-16-199:~$ aws s3 ls s3://elasticmapreduce/samples/hive-ads/libs/
2009-10-01 17:20:36       2433 join-clicks-to-impressions.q
2009-10-01 17:20:36     139640 jsonserde.jar
2009-10-01 17:20:36       1258 model-build.q
2009-10-01 17:20:37       1251 response-time-stats.q
2009-10-01 17:20:37        274 split_user_agent.py
2010-08-19 00:04:47       1789 twitter-impressions.q
2010-09-22 21:12:32      32441 upload-to-simple-db
2009-10-01 17:20:38        375 wait-for.sh`

Answer (score 1):

Download the jar from the below link

http://elasticmapreduce.s3.amazonaws.com/samples/hive-ads/libs/jsonserde.jar